# Update @IBOutlets via model

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, mvvm

I'm trying to decouple my outlets from the controller in order to migrate the view logic into a view model. Ideally I would like to be able to call an updateUI method from within the controller and have it filter down to the labels and text fields within the storyboard.
How I envisioned it working would be as follows:

Inside my controller:

```
var updateUI: ViewWithFieldsInside {
    return ViewWithFieldsInside.reloadData(newData)
}
```

Inside my view I would have all the outlets hooked in via a UIView class (linked to from storyboard) and have a reloadData method that would set the values equal to `newData`

Is this the correct way to handle this via Storyboard implementation or am I missing something?